# Javascript Fib series test case fails

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

I am trying to complete this assignment for the Javascript Fibonacci series. The logic works for input 5 and 6. But the test case for 8 fails.

```
function fibonacciSequence(input) {
    //Type your code here.
        var i = 0;
    var fib = [];
    fib[0] = 0;
    fib[1] = 1;
    
    var out ="0"+ "" +"1";
    
    for (i = 2; i <=input; i++) {
        fib[i] = fib[i-2] + fib[i-1];

    out = out+ ""+ fib[i];
    console.log("i is" + i + " out is" + out);
        
    }  


    return out;
}
```

I cannot figure out what is going wrong..

Answer (score 0):

It seems like things are just getting messed up with how you are adding the items to the string. Since there is no space between `out + "" + fib[i]`, I think that would be messing with the formatting. Once i had spaces it seems to work fine, a double digit number wouldnt mess with a string like that.

```js
function fibonacciSequence(input) {
    var fib = [];
    fib[0] = 0;
    fib[1] = 1;
    let out = ""
    out+= ` ${0} `
    out+= `${1}`
    for (let i=2; i <=input; i++) {
        fib[i] = fib[i-2] + fib[i-1];
        out+= ` ${fib[i]}`
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Sorry , I missed to include the expected result.. fibonacciSquenence(5) should return "0 1 2 3 5".  When I run it with input  8, the Output (stdout) shows 
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
1
3
2
1

Comment: It looks like the issue is how the characters are stored in array, The last two numbers (13 and 21) are 2 diigits. So they are being printed separately

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the input (which it seems like this is maybe the number you want to stop at) to i which (plus or minus a bit) is the number of numbers in the list. You probably want to be comparing fib[i], or something like it to input to decide whether to terminate the loop.

Edit: If that's wrong and you do want input to be the number of numbers in the list, then you could just join fib at the end:

```js
function fibonacciSequence(input) {
    //Type your code here.
    var i = 0;
    var fib = [];
    fib[0] = 0;
    fib[1] = 1;
    
    //var out ="0"+ "" +"1";
    
    for (i = 2; i <=input; i++) {
        fib[i] = fib[i-2] + fib[i-1];

    //out = out+ ""+ fib[i];
    //console.log("i is" + i + " out is" + out);
        
    }  


    return fib.join(' ');
}

for(let j = 0; j < 9; j++)
  console.log('input: ' + j + ' :: ', fibonacciSequence(j));
```

Unless ... I've got the wrong end of the stick and @Grant Herman's answer already does what you want?